# Maven/Spring with Browserify: require is not defined

Tags: node.js, maven, npm, spring-boot, browserify

I'm using Eirslett's [frontend-maven-plugin](https://github.com/eirslett/frontend-maven-plugin) which is a Maven plugin that downloads Node & NPM locally. I'm trying to use Browserify via that plugin.

I have installed Browserify with commands `npm install -g browserify` and `npm install --save-dev browserify`. Binary files of Browserify are downloaded correctly under `projectname/node_modules/browserify`.

I have an `test.js` file in `projectname/src/main/resources/static/test.js` which has the following code

```
var hiObj = {
  sayHi: function(){
    return "Modules"
  }
}

module.exports = hiObj;
```

I have `script.js` in `projectname/src/main/resources/static/script.js` and that file is added as an static resource in my HTML.

`script.js` looks like this

```
var obj = require('test.js');
console.log(obj.sayHi());
```

But when I try to render `index.html` I got this in my console

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined

How to get this working?

Answer (score 1):

Use a buildtool like **Grunt** or **Gulp**. With Gulp you can use the Browserify API directly and use it in a Gulp stream, for example:

```
var browserify = require('browserify');

// Stuff

gulp.task('js', function() {
  return browserify(package.paths.app)
   .pipe(/** Do stuff */);
   // More processing
});
```

For Grunt there is the [grunt-browserify](https://github.com/jmreidy/grunt-browserify) module.

Comment: I can already use `require` in my gulpfile and it's working, but `require` is not defined outside of `gulpfile`. I bundled my `test.js` as you said and require it in `projectname/src/main/resources/static/script.js`, but require is not defined.

Comment: That's what I'm trying to say, you have to use Gulp/Grunt to compile your JavaScript client code so that the `require()` stuff is resolved.